# ruby/rails on freehostia.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Internal Server Error 500

http://tekknolagi.co.cc/cgi-bin/test.rb

it doesn't run... is this an htaccess issue?

how can i fix it? it's just a simple

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "hello world"
```

Comment: Does freehostia.com support Ruby/Rails hosting? I don't think so.

Comment: If it supports Python, SSI, and PHP why not?

Comment: I can run the Ruby but if i run it inside a PHP file using `system()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the permissions on that file? It needs to be executable.

```
chmod +x test.rb
```